# how to trigger a scroll inside a website element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I am trying to load the full follower list on my instagram using iMacros. I have tried all the conventional recording mode, but it doesn't seem to be loading/scrolling to the entire follower list.

I also tried the javascript scrollby command which actually works on the website itself, but it doesn't work on the "Follower List" part of the page.. :(

```
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)
```

This is the element i am trying to get to load:

[image: Instagram Follower List]

I am basically just trying to load the entire follower list, so that iMacros is able to see the full list and then scrape the data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Instagram (Facebook, Twitter etc.) web pages it's better always to use the 'EVENT' scrolling. Regarding your issue I mean something like this:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="div[class='_4gt3b']" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div[class='_4gt3b']" KEY=35
```

Comment: hey buddy, as usual.. your the man.. this works perfectly on Firefox, but I am unable to get it to work on Chrome.. Any way to get it to work on Chrome too? :O